# Invention's legal assignee no longer exists; can I patent?

Tags: patentability

If inventions or ideas were created while employed at a company that uses the "standard" policy of having all inventions created by an employee assigned to the company, the company has not patented the inventions or ideas, and now the company no longer exists...

What are my options on patenting the inventions or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is not public knowledge you should be able to file a patent.

The ownership could still be claimed by your former employer, but they would have to prove that the idea was conceived and developed on their time, and not as an independent work.

And even then, inventions are rarely created in isolation and most new ideas are variations or improvement on old ideas, so even if your old employer had an idea they could never patented your evolved idea, which you would patent, and be sufficiently different to qualify as a unique and new invention separate from the idea that was never patented in your old company.